# Is it true that the minimum number of factors a number can have are two (one and itself)?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I feel silly for asking this but I am writing a function which part of it checks whether or not a number is prime and I need to know that this always applies when considering all positive integers. If it is true then I assume that any number that only has two factors must be prime and therefore we can check its primeness by counting the number of factors.

Comment: Well, 1 is an exception which only has 1 factor (but also 1 is usually not considered prime).  But otherwise, $n$ always has 1 and $n$ as factors which means it has at least 2 factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, all positive integers greater than 1 can be expressed as a product of primes.

That is; 
$n = p_1^{k_1}.p_2^{k_2}...p_n^{k_n}$.

Now, for all integers, the number of factors of that integer is given to be:
$(k_1+1)(k_2+1)...(k_n+1)$
Therefore, an integer has only 2 factors if, and only if, one of $k_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$, is equals to 1. This means that all the other values of $k_j, j \neq i$ is equals to $0$.

If $k_i = 1$, this simply means it is a prime number. So yes, it is true that an integer greater than 1 is prime if, and only if, it has 2 factors.

Comment: Minor point, you don't have to exclude $1$ in your characterization of primes. $1$ has only one factor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say what you mean by "only has two factors". Clearly $3\cdot 5=15$ has only two factors, but is not prime by definition. So we do not count $\pm 1$ as a true factor. The reason is, that the definition of a *prime number* is, that $p$ is prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., that for all $a,b$ we have that $p\mid ab$ implies that $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, $p$ then is irreducible, i.e., cannot be decomposed into a product of two factors both different from $\pm 1$.

Comment: The question title seems to consider both $1$ and $15$ as factors of $15$, so $15$ has four factors.

Comment: Yes, $\pm 1$ are not factors.

Comment: "Yes, ±1 are not factors"  According to whose dictionary?

Comment: @fleablood I mean, according to "irreducible", which says that one of the factors must be a unit, i.e., $\pm 1$, so not a "true" factor. Clearly we can also consider $\pm 1$ as factors, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If we only consider positive integers (which is what I'll mean by "number" in this post) and if we consider all factors including one and itself, then all numbers will have $1$ and itself as factors.  Primes will *only* have $1$ and itself as factors, composites (non-primes) will have $1$ and itself and at least one other factor.  So.

- no number has $0$ factors.  A number will always have $1$ and itself as factors.
- if a number has exactly one factor, it must be $1$ and itself so "itself" equals $1$.  Thus $1$ has one factor and it is the only number that has one factor.
- if a number has exactly two factors, those factors must be $1$ and itself and there are no others.  This is the definition of prime.  This is true for all non-$1$ primes (by convention $1$ is neither prime nor composite but **unitary**) and is only true for non-$1$ primes.
- if a number has more than two factors, these are $1$, itself, and at least one other.  This is the definition of composite.  This happens if and only if a number is composite.

So, no, the minimum number of factors a number can have is $1$, not $2$.

And, yes, you can tell if a number is prime, composite or equal to $1$ by counting the factors.

Note:  $0$ is considered a composite number with an infinite number of factors because $0*k = 0$ for all $k$.

Note 2: You might find it interesting that if a number has an odd number of factors it is a perfect square.  If a number has an even number of factors it is not.

So not only can you tell if a number is prime or composite by counting its factors, you can also tell if it square or not.

(This is because for any factor $a$ of $n$, then $a/n$ will also be a factor.  So we can pair up every factor $a$ with $n/a$ to get an even number of factors.  If however $n/a = a$ we can not pair $a$ to itself and $a = n/a$ is (literally!) the "odd man out".  But $n/a = a$ is a factor if and only if $a^2 = n$ and $n$ is a perfect square.)